# How to copy files from one remote server to another (LFTP)

Tags: linux, scp, lftp

Disclaimer: I have little Linux/sysadmin experience.

I am trying to transfer some files to someone else's remote server. The source files are available on my local Windows machine or our own remote Linux server. Initially I tried simply connecting via an FTP client on my Windows machine but it wouldn't allow me to (neither FTP nor SFTP). Note also that his server has a certificate issue.

I tried SCP from our server but it will not allow me to.

So he told me to SSH into our Linux server and use LFTP to connect to his. I managed to get it to connect by using `set=ssl-allow off`. But now I don't know what to do.

How do I transfer files from our server when I am connected to his machine on LFTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use winscp client just login with username/password you're allowed to login with .

https://winscp.net/eng/index.php